# Ignore certain packages and their dependencies with pip freeze

Tags: python, pip

Title basically says it all. How can I tell `pip freeze` to ignore certain packages, like `pylint` and `pep8`, and their dependencies?

Comment: Try [pipreqs](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few options available

## Try simple ignorance

Simply do not care about these packages being present in `pip` output.

## Delete these lines from output

Filter the output through some `grep` filter and have the result clean.

## Use virtualenv and do not install unwanted packages into it

Note, that pip freeze in virtualenv does not report globally installed packages (however it typically reports `argparse` and  `wsgiref` for me - nothing seems to be really perfect.)

## Write your own `pipwarm` command

which would call pip freeze and modify the output as needed (removing unneeded files).

I am aware, I probably did not give you the answer you asked for, but maybe the virtualenv is close to what you need, as it allows global presence of those packages and still allow not having these packages in output of pip freeze.

## Install `pep8` and `pylint` as scripts but keep them away from pip visibility

In case, you just care about having `pylint` and `pep8` available as command line tools, but do not require them visible to `pip freeze`, there are multiple options

### Install `pep8` and `pylint` into virtualenv and copy the scripts to `/usr/bin`

If you install `pylint` and `pep8` into separate virtualenv, find location of the executables by `which pep8` and `which pylint` and copy these files somewhere, where they will be visible, e.g. to `/usr/bin`. The scripts you copy or move from virtualenv have hardcoded path to required python packages in the virtualenv and will safely run even when copied (just the scripts, do not touch the rest of related virtualenv). Note, that there is no need to activete given virutalenv to make that working.

### Install `pep8` and `pylint` system wide but keep developing in virtualenv

System wide installed command line tools are typically installed into location, which makes them globally visible. At the same time, system wide installed packages are not seen by `pip freeze` when called in virtualenv.

Comment: The virtualenv is part of the problem. I have to install certain utility programs like `pylint` and `pep8` into the virtualenv to be able to fully check the source code with them, but I do not want to deploy them to the server. This is Heroku, so deployment involves a `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Thus, this leaves me with my current solution, which is to manually discover their dependencies through something like a fake pip install, then manually delete all the lines with vim, or just ignore it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Do you really need these packages to be available for import, or it is enough to have it available as command line tool?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist here you are. Answer extended to cover installation of command line tools in such a way, they are usable, but do not spoil our `pip freeze` output.

Comment: Unfortunately, the globally installed `pylint` will also create a ton of spam about failing imports because it is outside the virtualenv and can't see them on the path.

Comment: Decided to accept because even though I was ultimately disappointed with the solution, I essentially went with your first option, simply declining to care that they are included in the output and needlessly installed.

Comment: This is not a good solution when you are developing in docker, also ignoring the packages that are used in development but not in production is not a good practice at all. This question should have been left without any accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

My approach is the following:

1. I my `.bashrc` I create the following alias: `alias pipfreezeignore='pip freeze | grep -vFxf ignore_requirements.txt'`
2. Create the virtual environment, and install first all the packages that I do not want to keep track of (i.e. `pip install jedi flake8 importmagic autopep8 yapf`).
3. Immediately save them in a `ignore_requirements.txt` file, as in `pip freeze > ignore_requirements.txt`.
4. Install the rest of packages (e.g. `pip install django`)
5. Use `pipfreezeignore > requirements.txt` (in the same folder where `ignore_requirements.txt` is) so I just get in `requirements.txt` the installed packages that are not in `ignore_requirements.txt`

If you always want to ignore the same packages (through all your virtual environments), you might redefine the alias as in `alias pipfreezeignore='pip freeze | grep -vFxf /abs/path/to/ignore_requirements.txt'`
Just make sure that no packages from `ignore_requirements.txt` are not actually necessary for your project.

Comment: Wow, what an elegant solution! With a bit of work this could even become a tool that tracks the dependencies of the rest of packages, so that if there's a dependency from your packages in common with any dependency of your ignored packages, it would not ignore it, as it'd be required for the project.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use `pip freeze --exclude <package>`, which excludes the specified package from the output. See the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-exclude).

Answer (score 2):

on windows with powershell:

```
 $exclude = 'pylint', 'pep8'  

 pip freeze |  
             Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_ } |  
             ForEach-Object { pip install --upgrade $_ }
```