# Is there a command / procedure to replicate pip libraries

Tags: python, pip

I have two machines A and B. Machine A is my dev environment and machine B is my deployment machine. Machine A has a bunch of pip libraries installed. Is there a way for me to install those same pip libraries on machine B. The only way I can think of right now is to do a pip list and install those libraries one by one. Is there a faster approach ?

Comment: Why not use virtual environment?

Comment: I am using virtualenv in pyton for my project

Comment: Are you saying we can clone a python virtualenv ?

Comment: if you are using virtual environment, don't you have a requirements.txt file or equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what requirements files are for.

On machine 1:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Copy the file to machine 2, where you do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Normally, that file would be in version control with the rest of your code, and you would have virtualenvs on both machines.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: and like the others said, you can `pip install -r requirements.txt` on Machine B

Answer (score 1):

@ehacinom's answer points to the right direction but is incomplete.

On the machine where packages are installed you need to do:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

While on the other, to install them you need to copy the file and then do:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

File name is trivial, though `requirements.txt` is generally taken as a convention. You may see that in many git repositories.

You can edit or remove the packages that are to be installed by editing the file manually or programatically. You may want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23642321/4396006