# How to use pip freeze --exclude?

Tags: python, shell, pip

I am working with django project, where I am creating requirements.txt with 
**pip freeze> requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.7
django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter==0.1.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-multiselectfield==0.1.11
djangorestframework==3.11.0
fuzzywuzzy==0.17.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.8
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

I want remove some packages like pandas, numpy and fuzzywuzzy
I am using pip freeze --exclude pandas, numpy, fuzzywuzzy > requirements.txt
but not getting right output

```
fuzzywuzzy
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.0.7
django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter==0.1.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-multiselectfield==0.1.11
djangorestframework==3.11.0
fuzzywuzzy==0.17.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
nltk==3.4.5
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==1.0.1
psycopg2==2.8.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.8
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

how to use pip freeze --exclude command?

Comment: Which version of pip? In 20.0.2 that doesn't seem to exist: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/

Comment: It seems this option does not exist in current versions of pip. However see this Q&A for more ways to exclude packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640182/ignore-certain-packages-and-their-dependencies-with-pip-freeze/43137206