# How to exclude a package from requirements.txt file

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm working with python and i noticed when creating requirements.txt file it includes autopep8 and it's dependencies even though they are not "required" for my project to work.

requirements.txt file

```
autopep8==1.6.0
pycodestyle==2.8.0
toml==0.10.2
```

Is there a way to exclude autopep8 or any other package when running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` since it can get confusing when using unnecessary packages for the project and i might remove a dependency accidently .

Comment: you can safely delete that line

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640182/ignore-certain-packages-and-their-dependencies-with-pip-freeze) may help.

Comment: @PaulH The issue was then installing e.g. pandas, it install  **six, pytz** and **python-dateutil** as depedencies and when removing them manually, i might delete one accidentally.

Comment: @NassimH Thank you for the post. it seems like in my case there is no good solution except just to ignore those dependencies in the requirements file.

Comment: have you tried filtering it via grep, e.g.: ```pip freeze | grep -v 'autopep8' > requirements.txt```

Comment: @Kristian When using grep i'd still need to add all the autopep8 dependencies also. `pip freeze | grep -v 'autopep8' 'pycodestyle' 'etc' > requirements.txt`

Comment: accepted answer in NassimH's link also shows good alternative, such as using venv