# How to exclude a package that exists on requirements.txt during installation?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, remote-server, requirements.txt

There is a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70430119/8523960) about `freezing into requirements.txt` but this one is about `installing from requirements.txt`.
I have a `requirements.txt` file on a remote server with:

`Pillow==8.2.0`
`nltk==3.6.2`
`notebook==6.4.0`    #<--- exclude this
`numpy==1.19.5`

& then I realize that I want to exclude `notebook==6.4.0` while running
`pip install -r requirements.txt`. How can we achieve this?

**One Possibility**: I could `comment` or `delete` the unwanted package from the `local server's requirements.txt` & then git-pushing back to remote server. How can I exclude a package without having to go to the local server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for this problem is using *nested requirements.txt*

1. Production packages in requirements.txt:

```
Pillow==8.2.0
nltk==3.6.2
numpy==1.19.5
```

2. Development packages in requirements_dev.txt

```
-r requirements.txt  # <- installs production packages
notebook==6.4.0
```

... and as always: [ReadTheDocs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/?highlight=requirements.txt#requirements-file-format)

Comment: Thank you for the tips, that will be applied in future developments. Now I wanted something to hack my way out of my current mess.