# python using packages across virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

Apologies for the lack of better title..

I wanted to know if the following is possible?

So currently I am using vs-code for python work. In vs-code I install some packages related to vs-code extensions, for example I use `black` for formatting. The package `black` is installed in my base python installation. But when I switch to a new virtual environment, I have to reinstall the package. I don't mind reinstalling the package, but when I do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, it includes these packages also as dependencies, which I don't want.

My first question is, how can I limit the output of `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to just include the packages which are actually used in project (by actually I mean, which I am importing). I am open to using other methods for creating `requirements.txt`.

My second question (sort of on a side) is, when I reinstall the package in new virtual environment, is it creating a new copy of files (given that the same package is installed in base environment). I am using conda for virtual environment and my guess is it is using some sort of caching mechanism to avoid multiple installation.

Thanks for your help and time...

Comment: For your first question, perhaps something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737741/how-to-list-all-python-packages-used-by-a-script-in-python3 ?

Comment: The simple and obvious solution is to manually build your `requirements.txt` to only  list the actual dependencies. Every time you `import` something new, also add it to `requirements.txt`. Don't use `pip freeze` for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640182/ignore-certain-packages-and-their-dependencies-with-pip-freeze